# How to implement windows phone 7 Autcomplete box searches in Listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to implement windows phone 7 Autcomplete box searches in Listbox.

I have listbox in which I have bind mydata and i have to use Autocomplete Box to search in listbox. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What behavior do you want?

Since you're using a ListBox, do you want the values filtered, or do you want the selection point to move to match whatever you've typed in?

One note, have you checked out the AutoComplete control from http://Silverlight.codeplex.com ?  Not a listbox implementation, but it might serve your purposes.

Comment: Actually when user will type word in Autocomplete box it should show the record highlighted in listbox which will match.